# MySQL query changes in table column

Tags: mysql

I have a large table in my database where I need to track changes in a column (serial and date). In other words track which date a serial changed. This  is the structure:

```
pvs
-----

- id (int increment)
- serial (varchar)
- pos_id (int)
- fecha (datetime)
```

Pos_id is the location so it matters too.

[image: A query on that table]

I guess I could use PL but it's already slow as it is to just query the information without any filtering.

EDIT:

I upload Excel files to the database which correspond to a date, so the "on update" solution is not feasible for me.

When I say changes in a column  I mean changes in the "Serial" column.

EDIT 2:

As you can see there are four columns and the "serial" column is repetitive. The observation is that this column changes overtime for that pos_id (it represents an installed device and they get broken, etc) so I need to get the rows where the change ocurrs. For example, in the picture let's suppose that later on in id 2900000 serial changes to another code like 312555654. The entry would be:

```
id | serial | pos_id | fecha
2900000 | 312555654 | 5 | 2018-04-25 00:00:00
```

So I need to get all those changes in one query and in such a way update other tables. If that's possible. I could use pos_id as a parameter.

Comment: you can add a column with the default value "on update current timestamp" so that every time you update a row the value gets updated whith the timestamp of the change

Comment: That's cool and since I use Laravel I already have that but the thing is those dates are in a report, they reflect past dates not the moment when they are physically updated.

Comment: use mysql binlog

Comment: your comment makes little sense to me. Unless you are talking about an "audi trail". That is a completely different story and requires an audit trail table to be setup

Comment: If you upload data using excel, then you probably need to tackle that problem during the import. We don't know how you update your data yet - you would need to add that relevant information in order for us to help you with that.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Sorry, your edit made your question even less clear. Originally it sounded like you want to track updates (that is why you got the "on update"-comment). Your first edit made it sound like the import step is somehow relevant, yet you didn't include anything about that step ("i have data in excel -> something happens -> changes should be logged"). Your 2nd edit makes it sound like you are looking for a query ("So I need to get all those changes in one query") and you mention other tables and want to do something unspecific there. Could you be more specific about what *exactly* shall happen?

Comment: I never said I wanted to track literal sql updates. I wanted a query from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the answer a bit later:

```
SELECT min(id), SERIAL, pos_id, MIN(fecha)
FROM pvs 
GROUP BY SERIAL, pos_id
ORDER BY MIN(fecha) DESC;
```

So that every time the serial changed it will show me the first date in which the new serial shows up.